# Añadiendo valores float error en NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo este código de NetBeans:

```
public class ExerciciPicinesDos {
    public static final float AMPLE = 300.3f;
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        float llarg1, llarg2, prof1, prof2;
        float llargNou, aux;
        int area1, area2, volum1, volum2, areaNou, volumNou;

        llarg1 = 150,5f;
        llarg2 = 80.5f;
        prof1 = 20.5f;
        prof2 = 35.5f;
```

el `llarg1` me da un error en el `show hints` dice `expected`.

¿Sabéis por qué no me deja poner este valor?

---

Y ahora me encuentro este problema, siguiendo el código

```
llarg1 = 150.5f;
llarg2 = 80.5f;
prof1 = 20.5f;
prof2 = 35.5f;

area1 = (AMPLE * llarg1);
area2 = (AMPLE * llarg2);

volum1 = (area1 * prof1);
volum2 = (area2 * prof2);
```

Me dice que es

> incompatible types, possible loss conversions de float a int

pero los valores son dos FLOAT, ¿por qué no me los deja multiplicar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escribiste una coma en el valor:

```
llarg1 = 150,5f;
           ^^^
```

Que debería ser un punto:

```
llarg1 = 150.5f;
```

---

Si luego se quiere asignar este valor a un entero, se puede convertir redondeando al valor más cercano con [`Math.round()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-float-). Ejemplo:

```
area1 = Math.round(AMPLE * llarg1);
```

- Otra opción sería directamente declarar a `area1` como `float`.

Answer (score 1):

El error esta en que la variable area1 esta declarada como int, lo que guardes en esa variable se convertirá en un entero, por eso te indica que perderás precisión lo correcto debería ser que area fuera float también, para que no pierdas precisión.

Por ejemplo realiza este ejercicio define 2 enteros y multiplicalos y asignalos a una variable double y veras que funciona, eso es por que el resultado de una división siempre puede contener decimales.

Lee un poco sobre los tipos de datos primitivos y clases wrappers en Java.

Saludos.